# Custom servlet in Vaadin + Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, servlets, vaadin, vaadin-spring-boot

I'm trying to reproduce a simplified version of the official [Vaadin Dashboard Demo](https://github.com/vaadin/dashboard-demo), but I'm using Spring Boot for managing dependencies.

In `DashboardServlet.java` file you will find this code:

```
public class DashboardServlet extends VaadinServlet {
    @Override
    protected final void servletInitialized() throws ServletException {
        super.servletInitialized();
        getService().addSessionInitListener(new DashboardSessionInitListener());
    }
}
```

The demo is using a customized servlet.

Question: how can this be achieved in Spring Boot? How can I make Spring Boot inject my custom servlet class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must create a manage bean which name is `vaadinServlet`, and you want to extend the `SpringVaadinServlet` class. This should work:

```
@Component("vaadinServlet")
public class MySpringVaadinServlet extends SpringVaadinServlet {

    @Override
    protected void servletInitialized() throws ServletException {
        super.servletInitialized();
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you need to override some parameters?  Using `@Bean public ServletRegistrationBean vaadinServlet()` in an `@Configuration` class doesn't seem to work.